# How can I deal with a low spot in a fiberglass shower pan?

Tags: bathroom, water, shower

The slope of the shower base is not quite right. Water will drain correctly at the front of the shower, but the water at the back does not flow towards the front. Likely because the floor is not really straight. There might be a very slight bump in the middle that causes the water at the back to stay trapped.

I have no appetite for breaking everything and replacing everything.

Is there a solution for this problem? Maybe a type of silicon or something that could recreate more of a slope at the end?

[image: shower][image]

Comment: Raising the pan surface would make the already shallow lip disappear. you've indicated that it _already_ overflows, so you'd need to raise to that level or higher. Have you put a bubble level on your floor? How far out is it?

Answer (score 0):

autobody filler might work out you can put a real thin layer of it then sculpt it with a sander then finish it off with enamel paint, assuming this is a fiberglass pan.  Make sure you don't create a slippery surface though.  Another way would be to remove the glass wall and completely resculpt this with filler than put down tile mastic and tile it with traditional grout including a new higher lip.  Then reinstall the glass frame.  I agree with you I would not start a project to tear out the pan.

Comment: I can't imagine body putty holding to a flexible plastic surface. It would also look and feel terrible.